# Casting idataset to ifeaturelayer in ArcObjects C#?

Tags: arcobjects, c#

I am try to casting idataset to ifeaturelayer i did not get any idea

here my code

```
            ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI.IMxDocument mxd = ArcMap.Application.Document as
                                                   ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI.IMxDocument;
            ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IMap map = mxd.FocusMap;
            ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IWorkspaceFactory wsf = new 
                        ESRI.ArcGIS.DataSourcesGDB.FileGDBWorkspaceFactory();
            ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IWorkspace ws = wsf.OpenFromFile(@"D:\ARC OBJECTS\TemplateData.gdb", ArcMap.Application.hWnd);
            ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureWorkspace fws = ws as ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureWorkspace;
            ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureDataset fd = fws.OpenFeatureDataset("World");
```

Comment: You can't cast a IDataset to IFeatureLayer. You have to create a layer from that dataset first, then you can cast that layer to IFeatureLayer.

Comment: cag is correct. Be sure to look at the documentation to see which interfaces are shared on an object. For instance for a [FeatureDataset class](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/FeatureDatasetClass_Class/0025000000mz000000/). You can see that it implements IDataset and a bunch of other interfaces. You can also click on IDataset and see all the classes that implements IDataset.

Comment: @cag that may be enough to write an answer if you include a link to the relevant documentation.

Comment: @danielm that may be enough to write an answer.

Comment: @PolyGeo, the OP is fairly on the right track until the last line where they go slightly astray... the difference between IDataset, IFeatureDataset and IFeatureClass are subtle but in this instance you can't get from IDataset to IFeatureLayer necessarily (the OP says IDataset but is really using IFeatureDataset) for the same sort of reason why you can't blindly cast ILayer to IFeatureLayer - it might work at runtime but isn't guaranteed.

Comment: @MichaelStimson I'll trust you on that :-)

Answer (score 3):

I think you're barking up slightly the wrong tree here.. you're opening "World" as a [FeatureDataset](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0025000002wn000000); if "World" is feature data, suitable to become a feature layer, then you want to open it as a [FeatureClass](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0025000002qs000000) using [IFeatureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//00250000032p000000) and not as a IFeatureDataset.

You can create a *new* [IFeatureLayer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/IFeatureLayer_Interface/0012000004tp000000/) and set the [.FeatureClass property](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0012000004w7000000) to the newly opened feature class to get an IFeatureLayer from an IFeatureClass:

```
IFeatureClass pFeatureClass = fws.OpenFeatureClass("World");
IFeatureLayer pFeatureLayer = new FeatureLayer();
pFeatureLayer.FeatureClass  = pFeatureClass;
pFeatureLayer.Name = "World";
```

This new feature layer will need to be added to the map if you want to see it and will have a default renderer (single symbol) applied but these are just refinements you can work on later.

Comment: Thank you,      "  world " is not a feature class it is a dataset name in that dataset 3 feature are there .Then how to we access as a feature class.             I tried your suggestion its show the no table found.

Comment: Ah, if it actually *is* a dataset then you need to iterate the feature classes with IFeatureDataset.Subsets http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//00250000017z000000. You have to create an IFeatureLayer for *each* feature class in the feature dataset to get the feature layers. This will return a real IDataset for each object in the feature dataset; check the IDataset.Type is FeatureClass before casting to IFeatureClass.